# Let span not take up or use space in order for close elements not to move when the span disappears

Tags: html, css, expander

Sorry for the convoluted title. Could not come up with anything better.

On a webpage I have centered text which is a year number. There is also an expander/collapse feature which expands/collapses text below the year number. The `[+]` sign is used to expand the text. The `[+]` sign is in the same line as the year. When the `[+]` is clicked, the sign moves to the end of the expanded text and turns into `[-]`.

At the exact time when the `[+]` sign is clicked and when it moves to the end, the year (that is `2015`) moves a bit to the right in order to take up some of the space which was used by the `[+]` sign.

My question now is: Is there some way to avoid this shift? In other words, can `2015 [+]` be moved to the right such that `2015` does not move when the `[+]` is clicked?

Link to the JSFiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4ba25fde/1/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

update **CSS**

```
.more-link{
  position: absolute;
 }
```

here is the working [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4ba25fde/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `position: absolute` on [+] if you don't want it to affect your layout.

```
.year {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.read-more {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -30px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/34zoj6a6/1/

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in your Fiddle:

```
.yearhead {
    text-align: left;
    width: 11%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

When plus sign is not present 2015 was getting centered.

Comment: Use pixel width instead percent.